# Are compile-time solutions valid?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have a couple answers here that work at compile-time and just posted another, and I was wondering if such solutions are allowed. I'm not talking about just proper functions that can run at compile-time, such as `constexpr` in C++, but also stuff like types that take type parameters and return other types or templates that do something depending on their arguments.

For example, here is a factorial function in Scala 3 using types and some imported black magic:

```scala
import compiletime.ops.int._
type Fac[X <: Int] <: Int = X match {
  case 0 => 1
  case _ => X * Fac[X - 1]
}
```

This does not return a value that can be directly printed. Instead, you would need `compiletime.constValue[Fac[6]]` to compute the factorial of `6`, and not all languages that allow compile-time shenanigans also allow you to turn a type into a value so easily. You might need to verify it using something like `val check: Fac[6] = 720` and see if the compiler throws an error or not instead - it's not as simple as just `print(factorial(6))`.

Are such submissions valid? And if so, what rules do they have to abide by?

Comment: I'm not going to post a full answer right now because I'd like to think more.  But I think it would probably be all around best if you just made a harness for running these types of answers.  This would technically make them a new language, and would make all existing rules clearly apply to these types of answers.

Comment: You can also do this stuff in Haskell, and [it has been done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/166594)

Comment: @WheatWizard That makes sense. For my own answers, I did write tests, but if the only way of checking a correct result is doing `val check: Fac[6] = 720` in some language, then that complicates things quite a bit. The Haskell question specifically asks for something to operate over types, but what about for "normal" questions where a program/function is expected?

Comment: Sorry I think I was unclear, those two comments are unrelated to each other.  I was suggesting that you write a program that takes in a C++ (or Scala or Haskell) program written in this fashion and attaches a bit of boilerplate code to the end to turn it into a complete program.  This program is technically a compiler so what you have is a "new" programming language, you can call it C++ templates or something.  Since it is a complete and standardized programming language there is no need for any special rules or meta rulings.

Comment: @WheatWizard Oh, I see. I guess that solves my issue.